# Present variable value in database

Tags: ios, database

I need to create a database file and present in it a variable value. I don't understand a lot in database so anyone have a sample code for me?

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Did you look for info on the subject, or at least try a tutorial? How would any code snippet help you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's quite a vague question but you can go with these links:

- [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)
- [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html)
- [Core Data snippets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008285)
- [Apple threaded Core Data sample app](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope that helps.